# AKS : kubectl exec & kubectl log exits in between while the process is running in the container still

Tags: kubectl, azure-aks

I am running the following kubectl exec & kubectl logs cmd at the same time on two different windows command prompt

```
kubectl exec ${pod} containername -n namespace -- bash -c "cd somebatch.ksh > /proc/1/fd/1 2>&1"

kubectl logs ${pod} containername -n namespace
```

both gets exited from the windows command prompt in between while the process is running in the container still.

If I run the kubectl logs cmd again, I could see the running logs

```
kubectl logs ${pod} containername -n namespace
```

What should I do to keep the kubectl exec & kubectl log commands running without exiting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can "tail" the logs command by including `--follow`.

The `exec` creates a shell in the container and runs the script. Once the shell is created and the script passed, the process **is** complete.

If you want to keep the session open, you should be able to `exec` just `bash` and then run the commands interactively. You may want to include `--stdin --tty`, i.e. `kubectl exec --stdin --tty ... -- bash`

Comment: kubectl exec --stdin --tty throws invalid option

Comment: I suspect you're not running the command correctly. Those are both valid flags. See [kubectl exec](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubectl/kubectl-commands#exec)

Comment: can you please explain these flags --stdin --tty? what does it do?

Comment: Please read the link to the docs that I included.